# Keyboard shortcut for Xcode's popup with current Issues

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm trying to find a keyboard shortcut that would allow me to open Xcode's popup with current Issues. Here's a screenshot that shows what I mean:

[image: Xcode]

Answer (score 4):

Hit <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>. It will bring in the left menu a list of current issues.

[image]

It's not the popup, but it brings the list of issues. I don't think there's a shortcut for what you want. Here is a list of all issue related shortcuts:

**Issue**

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>

**Show Issues**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>

**Jump to Next Issue**

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>

**Jump and Fix Next Issue**

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>

**Jump to Previous Issue**

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>

**Jump and Fix Previous Issue**

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>

**Show All Issues**

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>

You can find information on Xcode shortcuts in this apple document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/Introduction/Introduction.html